# CSS placing div on top of image

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to move a select over my "header" image.

The problem is that when I `float:left` it obviously just sits right underneath the image. I have tried using margin and padding and neither seem to be helping me in this situation. What am I doing wrong?

**The correct placement (red box):**
[image]

**The wrong placement where I have it right underneath the entire image:**
[image]

**This is my coding:**

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="header">
    <img src="/images/placeholder_header.jpg" width="100%" height="215"/>
</div>
<div>
<select id="language" style="float:left;">
    <option value="">Select Language</option>
</select>
</div>
```

I have tried so many things but mostly:

```
#language { margin:5px;}
```

or `padding` or `position:relative` or `z-index` and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few options, I'll just show two of them:

```
#language {
    margin-top: -30px; /*adjust this value as needed*/
}
```

Also try this if the above one didn't work for you:

```
#language {
    position: relative;
    top: -30px; /*adjust this value as needed*/
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

**Note:** z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

Answer (score 1):

This is the purpose of position:absolute :

```
#header {
position: relative;
}

#language {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

And move #language inside #header.